# How to call a method on the Client side

Tags: java, sockets, client, keyword

I want to create chat server and I need to be able to do some things like clear the screen of a specified client, I thought about it and I figured that it would be a good idea if I would send a keyword to the client:

clientSide eg:

```
if((sporocilo = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    if(sporocilo.equals("clearTheScreen"{
        object.clearMyScreen
    }
}
```

However there are a lot of commands and the source code would be huge, plus once a client figures out the keyword he could exploit it, how could I do that in another, better way?

Comment: use an extra socket for sending/recieving those commands?

Comment: or use encrypted RMI...

Comment: work with serializable objects

Comment: You can try [`RMI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) (as long as you have control over both server and client code).

Comment: Can you explain how the client can exploit it? Clients don't communicate directly with other clients right? Therefore you can't force this on other clients. 

You need to be more worried about what the client sends to the server. As a server, you never trust user input. You check everything.

Comment: Come to think about it, why would the server tell the client to clear the screen? This seems like a client feature. The server doesn't even need to know about it. It's strictly client-side.

Comment: @Cruncher - Good idea, i will simply filter out the messages sent by the client. Clearing the screen was simply an example, there is lots of other stuff.

Comment: @PhilippSander - How do i do that?(i'm a newbie) Should i create a new Thread and read the messages from another server port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any example like FTP. Port 20 is used for default data and port 21 is used for Control(authentication etc).And different port mean different socket. After all socket is IP + Port no.

Same is in your case. Use different ports for actual chat data and your service instructions(like clear screen though i don't see why server must clear clients screen). Also instead of string commands like `"clearTheScreen"` use service ID's and keep a mapping of service ID to functions to be executed. Because if you keep simple string with names like "clear" or "password" with it then it will be easy for other to manipulate data(if it is not encrypyted ofcourse which is another good way to send data).

Comment: I did the same for one of my program - Neteye, although used the same port, but just passed IDs instead of string instructions. Instead I had something like
<controlbyte> SPACE <message-length-2-bytes> SPACE <message> so never required any separate message format for commands.